# Getting a query result from parent message

Tags: mysql, join

I am creating a message application and in my message, I want to get the query of a situation like this:
If the sender sends the message to the recipient and the recipient replies, then I want to get the parent message in the message_tbl with reply details on message received table.

Here is my database structure:

```
create table message_tbl(
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    message longtext,
    date datetime,
    parent_msg int,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

create table message_sent(
    msg_id int,
    from_id int,
    delete_status tinyint DEFAULT 0,
    FOREIGN KEY (msg_id) REFERENCES message_tbl(id)
);

create table message_received(
    msg_id int,
    to_id int,
    delete_status tinyint DEFAULT 0,
    is_read tinyint DEFAULT 0,
    FOREIGN KEY (msg_id) REFERENCES message_tbl(id)
);

INSERT INTO message_tbl values(1,'{"msg_subject":"hahaahaha","msg_content":"hahaha"}', '2020-05-24 05:50:23',0);
INSERT INTO message_tbl values(2,'{"msg_subject":"this is reply","msg_content":"reply test"}', '2020-05-24 05:50:23',1);

INSERT INTO message_sent values(1,31,0);
INSERT INTO message_sent values(2,30,0);

INSERT INTO message_received values(1,30,0,1);
INSERT INTO message_received values(2,31,0,0);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f69531/5/0

I want to get data something like these

```
id     message                                                  from_id      is_read     to_id     date                                                                                            
1     '{"msg_subject":"hahaahaha","msg_content":"hahaha"}'         1            0         2      202005-24 05:50:23
```

Comment: I assume you designed your table structure that way to make it possible for a message not be sent or to be sent but not received? Perhaps a message can be sent to multiple other users? I'm just trying to understand the logic behind the structure.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I want to get the parent message from message_tbl if there is a reply from it with the message received table it means the one who wrote the parent message received a response from another user. the from_id and to_id are the id's of sender and recipient

Comment: You know that MySQL supports a JSON data type, right?

Comment: @Strawberry yes.

Comment: But you weren't tempted?

Comment: when I got the data that I need. I just simply json_decode it in PHP

Comment: And presumably a multiple users can send the same message?

Comment: no. just private message. I just want to get the parent message and display it to the inbox of the sender if there is reply on the message

Comment: I still cannot figure out how you can decide who sent what to whom...unless there's always just one sender and one receiver for each message, which makes this structure very cumbersome.

Comment: !?!? We digress, but if all you're doing is decoding, why encode it in the first place?

Comment: Get rid of the message_sent table

Comment: I want to have a query that if the sender receives a reply to the recipient, then i want to get the details of the parent message which the sender sent, then i want to get the details of the reply receiver id's and etc.

Comment: Please consider the possibility that starting with a bad database design might make doing what you want a lot harder. I'm not saying that this is the case here, but only that it looks like that to me. A good design should make writing queries relatively easy.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thanks for a suggestion. It's very hard for me to change db design right now.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i think you just misunderstand my question since I cannot clearly explain it

Comment: @KIKOSoftware something like this what i mean: SELECT
message_tbl.id,
message_tbl.message,
message_tbl.parent_msg,
message_tbl.date
FROM
message_tbl
INNER JOIN message_received ON message_tbl.id = message_received.msg_id
WHERE
message_tbl.parent_msg = 0 AND message_received.delete_status = 0 AND message_received.to_id = 31

but cant get the parent message

Comment: @Strawberry i updated the SQL Fiddle

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i update SQL Fiddle

Comment: You still have the message_sent table, which, from your explanation, is redundant

Comment: @Strawberry I just want to have a query with these table structure if there is a new message that is unread to make my parent message unread